# How to properly do Class in-function caching in PHP

Tags: php, class, caching, static

What is the best practice way to do Class in-function caching in `PHP`. Right now I am doing:

```
Class Functions {
     public static function foo() {
         static $local_result;

         if(!empty($local_result) {
             return $local_result;
         }      

         $result = some_slow_http_request();
         $local_result = $result;
         return $result;
     }
}
```

So:

```
// First request makes an http request
Functions::foo();

// Second time, pull from memory, does not make an http request
Functions::foo();
```

Is there a better way? Are namespace collisions possible if code somewhere else changes `$local_result`, thinking it is a separate var?

Comment: $local_result is a variable local to the function `foo()` with the only difference being it doesn't get deleted after the function call. This is a fine method for caching on a per request basis, though you may want to look into Memcache, Opcache and APC.

Comment: Keep in mind that this approach only "caches" per request to YOUR server. What I mean is, if you run this script 2 times, the cache is not preserved in the second one.